# calling PDO with AJAX, returns an empty string

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, pdo

I have a simple database query written in PHP using PDO. When I `var_dump` my `$results`, I get an associative array. So I figured I'd just use `return $ result`, call the script using AJAX and then work from there. But now when I `console.log` the data I get, I just get an empty string.

Can somebody explain what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it? Thanks

Here's my php (I've emptied host, username and password for "safety"):

```
<?php
try {
    $hostname = "";
    $username = "";
    $password = "";

    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=topdecka_PTC",$username, $password);

    $raw_result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM articles');
    $result = $raw_result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $result;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
?>
```

and my AJAX function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get( "db_queries/all_articles.php", function( data ) {
    console.log( data );
});
});
```

Comment: instead of return use echo json_encode($result)

Comment: Are you sure you have a successful connection

Comment: @Uchiha yes, after changing it to echo json_encode it works as intended, just waiting for enough time to pass so I can accept the anwser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to echo JSON encoded data:

Change this line:

```
return $result;
```

To:

```
echo json_encode($result);
```